# Bash - Replacing or Removing first occurence in string bash

Tags: mysql, string, bash

I know this is a very common question. But I've looked through SO and google but I'm still unable to remove the first occurance or first few characters of a string which I retrieved from mysql.

I've got a table like this.

```
Name | Age

James| 27
```

My sql query (Select name from Human)

Once I execute the command from my bash script, it retrieves the row name (Name) and entry (James) in this form `Name James` when I only need `James`. How do I remove the word `Name` (including the space after it)? I want to store the result in a string and not echo it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is the mysql command line option `--skip-column-names` which will prevent the first line containing the column names to be returned with the `SELECT` query.  Try that.